# Is there a way to import a python script into a GUI without rewriting the whole script?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, user-interface, python-3.6

I have a python script that incorporates Excel sheets being imported, written, and that also contain username and password information. I received the massive script from a friend. It is very long and intricate and I need to incorporate it into a GUI. What is the best way to do this without having to rewrite and edit the whole script? I am a beginner to most of this.

Comment: Is it prompting for user input? Is its functionality encased in a function? You may be able to run it as a separate thread in the GUI. You may also be able to execute it as a subprocess.

Comment: That depends on what you mean "incorporate" it.  No matter what you do, you'll still have to write the GUI.  You could potentially call the script as a subprocess, but that will limit how you can interact with it.  There is also [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) which can make a well-designed command-line utility into a simple GUI.  But overall, your question is too broad.  Everything depends on how the original program was written.

Comment: yes, there is prompting for user name and password.
How would I call the script? and from what?
I will check out Gooey.
The script basically asks for user, password, then allows certain permissions such as what prompts are brought up. The user can choose a task to do choosing a prompt and enter when it is complete.
Ive been messing with Tkinter but am so confused. I guess I need to sit back, slow down and read the documentation and tutorials.
All data is connected to an Excel sheet including users, pass, and prompts given depending on user level. Script contains lots of functions + loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with [PyQt](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/) and read about the model-view structure it implements. Design a layout with Designer, then connect GUI buttons (signals) with functions written in the script (slots) to perform the functionality.

Comment: Well i have Qt installed but it always takes me to QT Creator. I want QT Designer and there seems to be nowhere online, including the official site, that I can find a link. All I want to use is Designer. I do not know C++ and need to make a Python GUI. I can open Design mode in QT Creator but there are no widgets such as buttons and etc. I just want QT Design. How can I get this? I have looked everywhere. @Brian

Comment: Qt Designer should come with PyQt. If it's on your system path, just type `designer` at the prompt. It's the same Qt Designer used for making C++ GUIs, but the output `.ui` file can be imported by PyQt. There is an excellent tutorial showing a step by step method of how to do this here: http://rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-1/ . It also adds matplotlib support, but basic buttons, signals, slots, etc should get you what you need.

Comment: Wow, i swear i already tried this. Maybe it is because i reinstalled it or was typing qtdesigner. Thank you! Now to figure out how to link it to python scripts... lol